# How are the field operator and quantum state after a beam splitter and a polarizing beam splitter individually?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

How are the field operator $\hat{a}$, $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and the quantum state (like coherent state $|\alpha>$, Fock state $|n>$) changed after a beam splitter and a polarizing beam splitter individually?

for example, two coherent states $|\alpha>$ and $|\beta>$ come into a beam splitter. $\hat{a}_{out1}=r\hat{a}_{\alpha}+it\hat{a}_{\beta}$, and $\hat{a}_{out2}=it\hat{a}_{\alpha}+r\hat{a}_{\beta}$, where $r^2+t^2=1$, and the output states are two coherent states with $\hat{a}_{out1}$ and $\hat{a}_{out2}$ operators separately. Is this correct?

But for a polarizing BS, a $\hat{a}=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}a_H+e^{i\phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}a_V$ comes into a HV PBS, what's the output? $\hat{a}_{out1}=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}a_H$ and $\hat{a}_{out2}=e^{i\phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}a_V$? If this is correct, $\hat{a}_{out1}$ and $\hat{a}_{out2}$ don't satisfy the commutation because of the sin and cos, which is $[\hat{a}_{out1},\hat{a}_{out1}^\dagger]=1$ and $[\hat{a}_{out2},\hat{a}_{out2}^\dagger]=1$. So is this wrong?

Comment: You didn't say why don't $\hat{a}_{out1}$ and $\hat{a}_{out2}$ satisfy the commutation rules? Because of the sine and cosine?

Comment: You don't need any prefactors for a polarizing beam splitter (PBS), i.e. $\hat{a}_{\rm out1} = \hat{a}_{\rm H}$ and $\hat{a}_{\rm out2} = \hat{a}_{\rm V}$. An ideal PBS will always transmit [reflect] all the horizontally [vertically] polarized photons.

Comment: jayann, then where have the cosine and sine coefficients been?

Comment: @LuZhang: I wrote an answer. Let me know if that clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 4):

I think one reason why confusion arises in trying to model a polarizing beam splitter (PBS) as quantum-optical device is because of the term *beam splitter*. However, functionally speaking, a PBS is a **polarizer** and is therefore not a reversible device. A single photon in the state $\alpha |H\rangle + \beta |V\rangle$ impinging upon a polarizer (say aligned along the horizontal polarization) will get transmitted with an $|\alpha|^2$ probability or absorbed with a $|\beta|^2$ probabilty. This clearly means the photon number is not conserved, or that the transformation by a polarizer cannot be unitary.

Now of course, an ideal (and lossless) PBS does not *absorb* the vertically-polarized
photon. In the above example, it would be available in **another** mode; say, at the
reflection port (if the horizontally polarized photons were obtained at the transmission
port).

One has then two choices: either neglect this other mode (which would then be exactly
like a polarizer) if it is not of interest, or consider it independently. I
emphasize on the *independence* because this could not be done for a normal beam splitter.
(This is also the reason why you cannot obtain interference in a PBS).

The mode relations in the Heisenberg picture (obtained by substituting $\eta = 1$ in equation 5.13 of this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0305007) on quantum physics of simple optical instruments) for an *ideal* PBS could be written as:
$$
\hat{c}_H = \hat{b}_H
$$
$$
\hat{c}_V = \hat{a}_V
$$
$$
\hat{d}_H = \hat{a}_H
$$
$$
\hat{d}_V = \hat{b}_V
$$
with $a$ and $b$ denoting the input modes, and $c$ and $d$ denoting the output modes, as also illustrated in this figure.
[image: Mode operators for polarizing beam splitter]

Note that $\eta = 1$ essentially stood for $\,\eta_H = \eta_V = 1$ so one could model a *realistic* PBS using $\eta_H < 1$ and $\eta_V < 1$ in equation 5.13 and derive the mode relations accordingly.

Given an arbitrarily polarized single photon prepared in mode $a$ (state $\alpha |H_a\rangle + \beta |V_a\rangle$), the evolution of this state through the ideal PBS would be described by:

$\alpha |H_a\rangle + \beta |V_a\rangle =  (\alpha a_H^{\dagger} + \beta a_V^{\dagger}) |0\rangle \rightarrow (\alpha d_H^{\dagger} + \beta c_V^{\dagger})|0\rangle = \alpha |H_d\rangle + \beta |V_c\rangle$

(I haven't used the hats on the operators to prevent cluttering).

You can see that the photon is a superposition of two different spatial modes $c$ and $d$ now.

Comment: Could you please explain the mode relations in the Heisenberg picture a little more? or give me some links. Thanks!

Comment: @LuZhang : I've updated the answer with a figure and a reference. Hope that helps!

Comment: can we denote the mode c and mode d outputs separately? For example, we have two inputs in mode a and b separately, I want to know the mode operators or the density operators of the two outputs in mode c and d separately.

Comment: In you reply, you explained how one photon state is changed after a PBS, which is a superposition of mode c and d. It would be more complicated for multi photon case. Does it mean we can only denote the whole output as an ensemble, and it's impossible to separate this state into two outputs in mode c and d?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for an *ideal* PBS. The basic transformation would be as follows: $|m^a_H, n^a_V ; p^b_H, q^b_V \rangle \rightarrow |p^c_H, n^c_V ; m^d_H, q^d_V \rangle$, with $m, n, p, q$ denoting *arbitrary* photon numbers, the superscripts [subscripts] denoting the spatial [polarization] modes. Since you can represent any state in the Fock basis, the above transformation for some multiphoton state containing both polarizations can also be accordingly evaluated.

Comment: For a non-ideal PBS, the situation would of course be more complicated. Nonetheless, my feeling is: if you can properly model the action on a single photon with arbitrary polarization, then the action on an arbitrary state could also be evaluated (should be a few lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

Of course $\hat{a}_{out1}$ and $\hat{a}_{out2}$ are O.K. We have the commutation rules

(**I**) $ \ [a_H, a^{\dagger}_H] = 1, \ \ \ [a_V, a^{\dagger}_V] = 1$, and $[a_H, a^{\dagger}_V] = 0. $

These are the commutation rules that the outputs have to satisfy, and they do satisfy.

What I think that confuses you is that you treated wrongly the beam-splitter (BS). You'd better consider a single beam landing on it, and see what happens. Otherwise you cannot compare with what happened at the polarization beam-splitter (PBS), because there you also considered a single input beam.

The output of the BS for a single beam is

(**II**) $ \ \hat a _{\alpha} \to t\hat a _{\alpha ,1} + ir \hat a _{\alpha ,2}$,

with $t$ is the transmission amplitude, real, and $ir$ the reflection amplitude, imaginary, and $r^2 + t^2 = 1$. I shortened "*out1*" and "*out2*" into 1 and 2.

The two outputs of the beam, although spacely separated, remain a coherent quantum superposition; if you bring them on a new BS, let's call it BS', and see that the path-lengths to BS' be equal except for a phase-shift of $\pi$ on the path of the reflected wave, they will emerge through one single output.

(**III**) $ \ t\hat a_{\alpha ,1} - ir \hat a_{\alpha ,2} \to t(t \hat a_{\alpha ,1 \to 2'} + ir \hat a_{\alpha ,1 \to 1'}) - ir(t\hat a_{\alpha ,2 \to 1'} + ir\hat a_{\alpha , 2 \to 2'})$

$ = (t^2 + r^2) \hat a_{\alpha ,2'} = \hat a_{\alpha ,2'} . $

The same with the PBS. The two outputs satisfy the commutation rules (1). As to the transformation at the PBS, it preserves the coherent superposition, as the BS,

(**IV**) $ \ \hat{a}=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}a_H + e^{i\phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}a_V .$

If you will input the two branches, now spacely separated, into the two input faces of a PBS', and take care of the path-lengths to PBS' and (if necessary) phase-shifts, the two components will exit through one single output face.

(Maybe my statement with exiting through a single output face of PBS', puzzles you. But, the transformation at the PBS is reversible as is the transformation at BS. The PBS' reverses the action of the PBS, i.e. reunites the two beams into one, as did BS'.)

Comment: First, $[a_{out1},a_{out1}^\dagger]=\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}$ not 1, that's why I said it doesnt satisfy commutation rules.

Comment: and I think $\hat{a}_{\alpha,1}=t\hat{a}_\alpha+ir\hat{a}_{vacuum}$ instead of eqn (2). I only consider the situation that BS or PBS separate the single beam (even is a combination of two modes), won't combine them again using BS' or PBS'.

Comment: @LuZhang commutator 1 you get for a normalized beam. For your $\hat a = cos(\theta /2) \hat a_H + e^{i\phi} sin(\theta /2) \hat a_V$ you get 1 because it's normalized. But how do you expect that part of an entire to be entire? Your outputs aren't normalized. If you define $\hat {out1} = \hat a cos(\theta)$ of course the commutator won't be 1. A similar thing occurs with the number operator, $\hat a^{\dagger} \hat a |n> = n|n>$ but $\hat a^{\dagger} \hat a |n>cos(\theta) = n \ cos(\theta)|n>$. I saw also you 2nd comment, but let's first clarify the normalization issue.

Comment: @LuZhang your equation $\hat a _{alpha} \to t \ \hat a _{alpha} + i \ r  \hat a _{vacuum}$ is impossible also because of normalization. If you multiply this equation by its complex conjugate, you get $\hat a^{\dagger} _{alpha} \hat a _{alpha} \to (t \ \hat a^{\dagger} _{alpha} + i \ r  \hat a^{\dagger} _{vacuum})(\hat a _{alpha} + i \ r  \hat a _{vacuum})$. On the LHS you have the number operator, on the RHS you have less than the number operator. But, as I said, let's first clarify your 1st question.

Comment: I understood your statement about part of an entire not entire. And the second comments, $\hat{a}_{\alpha}$ does satisfy the commutation. $\hat{a}_{\alpha}\hat{a}_{\alpha}^\dagger-\hat{a}_{\alpha}^\dagger\hat{a}_{\alpha}=t^2+r^2=1$.

Comment: @LuZhang I am not so sure whether you understood my 2nd explanation. If you write $\hat a \to t \hat a _{transmitted} + i \hat a _{reflected}$ is O.K. The operator $\hat a$ doesn't establish how many particles we have, s.t. the notation $\hat a _{vacuum}$ is wrong. To illustrate, let's apply $\hat a^{\dagger}$ to the vacuum state (in our case it's more intuitive to work with the creation operator.) We get $\hat a^{\dagger>} |0> \to \left( t \hat a^{\dagger} _{transmitted} + i \hat a^{\dagger} _{reflected})\right)|0>$. We get $|1> \to t|1>_{transmitted} + ir |1>_{reflected}$. No vacuum.

Comment: you are considering the two outputs as a whole beam. What I did is I only calculate one output, I add a vacuum operator because I assume there is only one input. Actually, I denote the two output operators using original operators. I think we are both right, just talking about different things. I dont know how you denote $a_{transmitted}$ using $a_{\alpha}$.

Comment: @LuZhang Aaaa, I seem to understand. No, the beam-splitter creates for ***one*** input, ***two*** outputs. You don't get two outputs from the BS because you bring two inputs. This is why it is called beam-splitter, because from one inputs it produces two outputs. There is another way of writing the output, but I am afraid that it can confuse you : $|1> \to t|1>_{transmitted}|0>_{reflected} + ir|1>_{reflected}|0>_{transmitted}$. Indeed, if one ***detects*** the particle as transmitted, one ***also*** detects ***no particle*** reflected. (I continue)

Comment: @LuZhang but, please notice, we have $|1>_{transmitted} \text AND |0>_{reflected}$ not $|1>_{transmitted} \text OR |0>_{reflected}$. The $|1>_{transmitted}|0>_{reflected}$ are written as a direct product, not as a superposition. In other words, if you input ***one*** particle, you won't find at the output EITHER one particle (on one side) OR no particle (on the other side). You will find ***one*** particle for sure, though it will be EITHER on one side OR on the other side. Particles ***don't disappear***.

Comment: yeah I got what you meant. I'm considering the case of a n Fock state $|n>$ as an input, instead of n single photons, which is easy to denote as you gave. That's why I want to use operator instead of quantum state to do the calculation. I'll think how to deal with my case.

Comment: @LuZhang : with $n$ particles the formulas will be more complicated, but still, the total number is conserved. The beam-splitter doesn't "*eat particles*". So, you will have $|n> \to q_0 t^n|n>_{transmitted}|0>_{reflected} + q_1 irt^{n-1} |n-1>_{transmitted}|1>_{reflected} - q_2 r^2 t^{n-2}|n-2>_{transmitted}|2>_{reflected} + etc.$